A question about total transform
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over complex numbers. Let $\pi:\widetilde{X}\to X$ be a blowup of smooth center $Z$. Now let $Y$ be an irreducible subvariety of $X$ containing the center $Z$. Assume that the strict transform $\widetilde{Y}$ of $Y$ is smooth.
I'm wondering if it is true that the total transform $\pi^{*}(Y)$ is the strict transform plus a Cartier divisor, i.e.,
$$\pi^*(Y)=\widetilde{Y}+nE,$$
where $E$ is the exceptional divisor, and $n$ is an integer?
More precisely, I want to ask if there are "unexpected" embedded components appearing in $\pi^*(Y)$.

Consider, for example, the blowup of a point on a plane and the total transform of a curve with a node at that point.

@Sasha Thanks, I fixed that.

Now the answer is positive because the relative Picard group of the blowup is generated by the exceptional divisor (assuming, of course, that $Z$ is connected).

@Sasha Yes, I assume $Z$ is connected, reduced, and smooth. There is nothing additional in codimension one, but why there is nothing supported over higher codimension strata of $Z$ where $Y$ becomes more singular? The concern I have is related to the subtle difference between the notions of "weak transform" and "strict transform", which is on p.21 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206244. On p.22, there is an example where an extra embedded component appears in the blow-up. The example in the paper differs from my situation. I'd like to know if this pathology can be avoided in my case
